# Bash Regex email matching

Tags: regex, bash, email

I'm trying to match up some email addresses using regular expressions in bash.
Currently got the expression

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%&'\*\+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%&'\*\+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\$"
```

Which successfully matches all the emails i need, however when trying to add the "To: "field i cant seem to get any matches and i'm not sure why. 
This is my code with the To field.

```
"^To:\s[a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%&'\*\+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%&'\*\+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\$"
```

Which AFAIK should match up fine with "To: bob@bob.co.uk" but doesn't :(
Any advice?

Example from code

```
Reply-To: "service@paypal.com" <service@paypal.com>
To: bob@bob.co.uk
Date: Mon, 21 Jun 2012 21:34:10 -0300
```

Code used to search file and add to array

```
regex="^[a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%&'\*\+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%&'\*\+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\$"


for i in $(cat mailbox.mbx); do 
    if [[ $i =~ $regex ]]; then
    echo $i
    sortarray[$index]=$i
    index=$(($index+1))
    fi
done
```

Comment: so does your string contain [email] tag or not? Does the email end with whitespace? Post the full string

Comment: No sorry it doesn't, that was auto input from a copy paste. It's now exactly as it should be.

Comment: post the full string containing email

Comment: It's parsing from a large file, but an example is shown exactly as above. 
E.G "To: bob@bob.co.uk"
On a line by itself. The first Regex picks it up fine, the second picks none up.

Comment: more information is needed, how does the email begin and end, with tag, whitespace, begin or end of line etc.

Comment: No tags, no white space, beginning of line (Only thing in the line)
It's quite literally as i have put above. Doesn't even work if that's the only thing in the file.

Comment: mate, if you need help, read the questions carefully and be more specific. I'll ask you one more and last time: 1) begin of line or begin of entire string/file? 2)How does the email end? you say no white space or tags. But how is your email separated from the whole string? Do you mean it's like To: bob@bob.co.uksomeothertexthere? Better post this email with some text before (if exists) and after.

Comment: 1) Beginning of the line, i have moved it to the beginning of a blank file with no line feed which made no difference. The first regex still worked however. 2) There is a line feed straight after the end of the email, however as the first regex picks up the emails fine it leads to believe that the problem is to do with the statement trying to pick up the "To: ".
Hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bash regexes don't understand the perl-ish `\s`. You have to use the posix-ish `[[:space:]]`. Also you should add a quantifier there

I see you have anchors in `$regex`: are those tripping you up?

For massive regular expressions like this, I like to build them up piecemeal:

```
char='[[:alnum:]!#\$%&'\''\*\+/=?^_\`{|}~-]'
name_part="${char}+(\.${char}+)*"
domain="([[:alnum:]]([[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])?\.)+[[:alnum:]]([[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])?"
begin='(^|[[:space:]])'
end='($|[[:space:]])'

# include capturing parentheses, 
# these are the ** 2nd ** set of parentheses (there's a pair in $begin)
re_email="${begin}(${name_part}@${domain})${end}"

line="To: joe.smith@example.com"

[[ $line =~ $re_email ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
# prints: joe.smith@example.com
```

Of course, email addresses are suprisingly complex -- http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/#z8 -- and comments and whitespace should be allowed just about anywhere. In fact, `(hi there) "My First Name".lastname (another comment) @ domain.(really)invalid` should be considered a valid address. There's a Perl module [Email::Address](https://metacpan.org/module/Email%3a%3aAddress) that generates this regular expression:

```
$ perl -MEmail::Address -E 'say $Email::Address::addr_spec'  
(?-xism:(?-xism:(?-xism:(?-xism:(?-xism:\s*\((?:\s*(?-xism:(?-xism:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?-xism:\\(?-xism:[^\x0A\x0D]))|(?-xism:\s*\((?:\s*(?-xism:(?-xism:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?-xism:\\(?-xism:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*)))*\s*\)\s*)|\s+)*(?-xism:[^\x00-\x1F\x7F()<>\[\]:;@\\,."\s]+(?:\.[^\x00-\x1F\x7F()<>\[\]:;@\\,."\s]+)*)(?-xism:(?-xism:\s*\((?:\s*(?-xism:(?-xism:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?-xism:\\(?-xism:[^\x0A\x0D]))|(?-xism:\s*\((?:\s*(?-xism:(?-xism:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?-xism:\\(?-xism:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*)))*\s*\)\s*)|\s+)*)|(?-xism:(?-xism:(?-xism:\s*\((?:\s*(?-xism:(?-xism:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?-xism:\\(?-xism:[^\x0A\x0D]))|(?-xism:\s*\((?:\s*(?-xism:(?-xism:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?-xism:\\(?-xism:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*)))*\s*\)\s*)|\s+)*"(?-xism:(?-xism:[^\\"])|(?-xism:\\(?-xism:[^\x0A\x0D])))+"(?-xism:(?-xism:\s*\((?:\s*(?-xism:(?-xism:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?-xism:\\(?-xism:[^\x0A\x0D]))|(?-xism:\s*\((?:\s*(?-xism:(?-xism:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?-xism:\\(?-xism:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*)))*\s*\)\s*)|\s+)*))\@(?-xism:(?-xism:(?-xism:(?-xism:\s*\((?:\s*(?-xism:(?-xism:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?-xism:\\(?-xism:[^\x0A\x0D]))|(?-xism:\s*\((?:\s*(?-xism:(?-xism:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?-xism:\\(?-xism:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*)))*\s*\)\s*)|\s+)*(?-xism:[^\x00-\x1F\x7F()<>\[\]:;@\\,."\s]+(?:\.[^\x00-\x1F\x7F()<>\[\]:;@\\,."\s]+)*)(?-xism:(?-xism:\s*\((?:\s*(?-xism:(?-xism:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?-xism:\\(?-xism:[^\x0A\x0D]))|(?-xism:\s*\((?:\s*(?-xism:(?-xism:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?-xism:\\(?-xism:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*)))*\s*\)\s*)|\s+)*)|(?-xism:(?-xism:(?-xism:\s*\((?:\s*(?-xism:(?-xism:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?-xism:\\(?-xism:[^\x0A\x0D]))|(?-xism:\s*\((?:\s*(?-xism:(?-xism:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?-xism:\\(?-xism:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*)))*\s*\)\s*)|\s+)*\[(?:\s*(?-xism:(?-xism:[^\[\]\\])|(?-xism:\\(?-xism:[^\x0A\x0D]))))*\s*\](?-xism:(?-xism:\s*\((?:\s*(?-xism:(?-xism:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?-xism:\\(?-xism:[^\x0A\x0D]))|(?-xism:\s*\((?:\s*(?-xism:(?-xism:(?>[^()\\]+))|(?-xism:\\(?-xism:[^\x0A\x0D]))|))*\s*\)\s*)))*\s*\)\s*)|\s+)*)))
```

Comment: What a great explanation, very informative and really helps, especially the splitting of regex and rebuilding through a variable.

Answer (score 1):

This Regex should match the needed string:

```
"^To: (.+@.+)$"
```

The email is stored in `$1`

Comment: Afraid not, without the "To: " it does match the email, but with it there is no match found. It also needs to implement the original regexp (or as close as possible, but i can fix that once the initial To: is found.) Added my code to the topic.

Comment: @DanFarrall in case of Reply-To: the email starts and ends with **"** but in case of To: it doesn't. Are you sure it's correct?

Comment: @DanFarrall you are missing something like tags, special symbols etc.. redirect the first output to the text file and see it with different text viewer/editor

Comment: I have tried using a plaintext file with only "To: bob@bob.co.uk" on a single line, the To: fails to match. Have you tested your solution and found it works? I am running off OS X but it shouldn't make a difference in this case, surely?

Comment: @DanFarrall I've tested it in c#, but that shouldn't make any difference as I didn't used perl or common regex specific elements.